# "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" using CoffeeScript TextMate bundle with Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, textmate, coffeescript, textmatebundles

I am trying to use this bundle with the coffee files generated for each controller. I'm just delving into this for the first time by just doing the traditional

```
$ ->
    alert('Hello World!')
```

It works fine when I view the page, and doing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> also displays the desired JS code. However, I can't do <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. I just get `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. I understand that it probably can't reference the jQuery file that defines `$`, but can't for the life of me figure out how to do that. Come to think of it, I'm wondering if it's a sensible thing to want to do this...

What's the best practice when using CoffeeScript and TextMate in Rails 3.1 development?

Thanks,
Dany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It works fine when I view the page, and doing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> also displays the desired JS code. However, I can't do <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Right, because <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> means "run this `.coffee` file under NodeJS" (basically equivalent to `coffee myfile.coffee`). Even if `$` weren't an issue (`$ = require 'jquery'` will fix this, after you `npm install jquery`), `alert` certainly would be.

Now, you might be thinking: "OK, crazy idea: What if I split my front-end into Node modules, which are easy to test, and then convert them to browser-friendly code for deployment?" In that case, I have good news for you: sstephenson stole your crazy idea months ago, and it's called [Stitch](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch). Give it a try!